# Determining whether the new date is the default new DateTime() or not

Tags: c#

Here is my question:

```
DateTime previousDate = new DateTime();
DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();
foreach (ApproverVo approver in approvers)
{
    if (previousDate != null)
    {
        currentDate = (DateTime)approver.ApprovalDate;
        totalTimeSpan += (currentDate - previousDate).TotalDays;
        previousDate = currentDate;
    } else
        previousDate = (DateTime)approver.ApprovalDate;
}
```

When the previous date is declared in the beginning, it contains the default value of DateTime(). What I want to do is to find out whether the previousDate has been assigned with proper date or not.

Advice please, thanks

Comment: A `DateTime` can't be equal to `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your approval date doesn't have value equals `DateTime.MinValue` :

```
DateTime previousDate = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();
foreach (ApproverVo approver in approvers)
{
    if (previousDate != DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        currentDate = (DateTime)approver.ApprovalDate;
        totalTimeSpan += (currentDate - previousDate).TotalDays;
        previousDate = currentDate;
    } else
        previousDate = (DateTime)approver.ApprovalDate;
}
```

**UPDATE**

According @mdmullinax answers, above code is similar with :

```
DateTime previousDate = new DateTime();
DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();
foreach (ApproverVo approver in approvers)
{
    if (previousDate != new DateTime())
    {
        currentDate = (DateTime)approver.ApprovalDate;
        totalTimeSpan += (currentDate - previousDate).TotalDays;
        previousDate = currentDate;
    } else
        previousDate = (DateTime)approver.ApprovalDate;
}
```

Comment: Would using 'DateTime?' or 'Nullable<DateTime>' be better than comparing to DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I found out that the first time a DateTime object is declared, it contains the MinValue of a date time. Though at the end, I use different approach to do the comparison ( if(previousDate != new DateTime())

Answer (score 2):

check if `previousDate == DateTime.MinValue` since

```
DateTime previousDate = new DateTime();
```

is equivalent to

```
DateTime previousDate = DateTime.MinValue;
```

from MSDN [DateTime Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-6) documentation:

```
DateTime dat1 = new DateTime();
// The following method call displays 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.
Console.WriteLine(dat1.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// The following method call displays True.
Console.WriteLine(dat1.Equals(DateTime.MinValue));
```