# Empty datetime in the report

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, telerik, telerik-reporting

I face the following problem :

Sometimes the value of my trans_in(`DateTime`) in my database is :`1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`

and it appears in my telerik report like this `12:00 AM` i want to show the textbox empty instead so i create the following custom method :

```
  public static string NotAttend(DateTime trans_in)
        {
            if (trans_in == null || trans_in.ToString().Trim() == "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000")
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
                return trans_in.ToShortTimeString();
        }
```

and bind the textbox like this :

```
= OvertimeReports.CustomExpressions.NotAttend(Fields.trans_in)
```

but this didn't fix my problem still appear `12:00 AM` !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `trans_in.ToString()` would return you the string representation of your `DateTime` object based on your current culture, its better if you check your `DateTime` like:

```
public static string NotAttend(DateTime trans_in)
{
   if(trans_in == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
   {
        return string.Empty;
   }
    else
        return trans_in.ToShortTimeString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem what you have here is more of a formatting issue with the `.ToString` conversion

Try using the specific format you need in the .ToString overload for this

`trans_in("yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss.fff")`

So in this `HH` case you would have it as 00:00 instead of 12:00

A better way would be to compare it as `DateTime` make a DateTime obj for 1900-1-1 then compare it with `trans_in.Date` part which would not involve this string formatting issues

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare the trans_in with `default(new DateTime())`

You shouldn't compare a date with a String without formatting it

reference:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/d0f4578c-0585-4f38-95be-569a90ebeb21/

edit: i'm seeing here you'd best compare with `DateTime.MinValue`
[Determining whether the new date is the default new DateTime() or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060618/determining-whether-the-new-date-is-the-default-new-datetime-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a format to your `DateTime` by using overridden function of `DateTime.ToString()`. `HH` means time in `24 HRS` where `hh` means `12 HRS` format :

```
 public static string NotAttend(DateTime trans_in)
 {
   if (trans_in == null || 
       trans_in.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") == "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000")
     {
       return string.Empty;
     }
   else
    return trans_in.ToShortTimeString();
  }
```